# How to greet two person in the beginning of a letter/email?

Tags: letter-writing, greetings

> Dear Prof. Hartman,
>
> Dear Prof. Dore,
>
> Thank you very much for letting me know about the result of my
>   application.

or

> Dear Prof. Hartman and Prof. Dore,
>
> Thank you very much for letting me know about the result of my
>   application.

?

Comment: "Dear Professor***s*** Hartman and Dove"

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, when all professors were men, you could have begun your letter with the salutation "Gentlemen,". In my lifetime that was an acceptable salutation in a letter to a firm (a partnership or company  comprising, it was presumed, men).

Obviously that does not work these days. But Hartmann and Dove are not a firm, which is in legal terms a distinct entity, and  you therefore have to decide to whom you are writing. I suggest you write a letter to Prof. Hartmann, and in the final sentence of that letter say something like "I am sending a copy of this letter to Professor Dove, with my thanks to him also."